# Selective sorting in solr

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I have many documents indexed into Solr. I am now facing a requirement where the search results should be returned sorted based on their `scores`. In the **case of non-exact matches**, if there is a tie, another level of sorting is to be applied on a field called `priority`.

I am using solr with django-haystack in django 1.4.

What can/should I do to achieve my requirement?

Comment: I have ordered the `SearchQuerySet` method by('-score', 'priority'), but this also applies to exact matches having the same score. What should I try to achieve the above?

Comment: @Hedde Is it even possible to achieve what I am trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boost in edismax can be used for this. It is applied to all scores, but if it is a small value, it will only make a difference for ties or near-ties. Significant differences in the base score will not be reordered.

See: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#boost_.28Boost_Function.2C_multiplicative.29

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of django or django-haystack, but if you want secondary sorting in solr you just specify multiple sorts as a comma seperated list. Example...

```
score desc, priority desc
```

...would sort documents by score, and if two documents have identical scores would then sort by the priority field.

Note however that this will only provide a secondary sort for things that have *exactly* the same score value -- you may instead want to "boost" the scores of your documents (ie: actually affect the score, prior to sorting) by your priority field.